# How can I exclude some results of the output in ProLog?

Tags: prolog, output

I'm new to ProLog and I'm having an issue. In the output i have two  similar results and I wish to exclude one of them. I'll paste the code and the query followed by the output so you can visualize.

```
methylation(m1).
methylation(m2).
methylation(m3).
methylation(m4).
methylation(m5).
methylation(m6).
...

gene(a).
gene(b).
gene(c).
gene(d).
gene(e).

related_genes(a,c).
related_genes(b,d).

gene_has_met(a, [m1,m2,m5]).
gene_has_met(b, [m1,m7,m8,m14]).
gene_has_met(e, [m20]).
gene_has_met(c, [m20]).

same(X,Y) :- X == Y.

genes_have_same_met(G1,G2,M) :- gene(G1), gene(G2),
    gene_has_met(G1,M),gene_has_met(G2,M),
    not(same(G1,G2)), same(M,M).

linked_genes(G1,G2) :- gene(G1), gene(G2),
    related_genes(G1,G2); genes_have_same_met(G1,G2,_).
```

When I ask the following query, I expected to obtain this result:

```
?- linked_genes(Gene1,Gene2).
Gene1 = a,
Gene2 = c ;
Gene1 = b,
Gene2 = d ;
Gene1 = c,
Gene2 = e ;
false.
```

However, I obtained this result:

```
Gene1 = a,
Gene2 = c ;
Gene1 = b,
Gene2 = d ;
Gene1 = c,
Gene2 = e ;
Gene1 = e,
Gene2 = c ;
false.
```

Has you can see, I have two similar results since its the equal to have **Gene1 = c** and **Gene2 = e** or the opposite. So I wanted to remove one of them from the output.
How can I do that?
Ty!

Comment: Characters are ordered (aplhapbetically), so you can just add `G1 < G2` or something.

Comment: I already have tried that solution. However, an error occurs: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function

Comment: You can use `@</2` for comparing general terms. `</2` is used for numbers only. The `@` comparison operators will do an ordering that makes sense. So apply the constraing, `G1 @< G2`.

Comment: It worked and it was so easy as that! I really should get into those ProLog details! Thanks lurker!